# What does Xamarin.Forms.Map display?

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I used this [Xamarin.Forms Map tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map) to create a simple app that displays a map and plots several points (from our database). The app works as it should, and that would normally be enough.

But I wanted to make my app different, and I wanted to use another type of map. For example, Waze and Google Maps both show me how to get to my nearest Walmart, but I like Waze's map more.

So my question is: what exactly does `Xamarin.Forms.Maps` display? It's a control that shows a map, but why does it show a Google Map instead of, say, a MapBox?

And since Google Maps and Waze are owned by the same company, why wouldn't I be able to display the Waze map instead of the Google Map?

Finally, what other map control options do I have? My app simply takes several coordinates from a sql table and plot the points in the map.

Comment: it uses the map control from the underlying platform: Apple Maps, Google Maps, Bing Maps, etc.

Comment: Thanks. Can I change Xamarin.Forms.Maps so that it displays something else besides Google Maps?

Comment: there are several alternative map controls you can try

Comment: You cannot change the behaviour of XF maps but you can directly use other Map plugins available there are many to say the least

Comment: Thanks. Is there a list somewhere that shows the available Map plugins? Or how do I search for alternatives?